# Casting `[<length> x i8]*` to `i8 *`

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to replace an argument to an existing function call. The initial argument is a global string and i'm trying to replace it with a local string.

No matter what i try i get a `Call parameter type does not match function signature!` runtime error.

Specifically i want to replace the argument to the `printf` function - `declare dso_local i32 @printf(i8*, ...) #1`. The call to it in the code looks like this:

```
@message = dso_local global [12 x i8] c"Hello World\00", align 1
...
%call = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([12 x i8], [12 x i8]* @message, i64 0, i64 0))
```

I allocate and GEP the local replacement string as such:

```
%0 = alloca [12 x i8], align 1
%1 = getelementptr inbounds [12 x i8], [12 x i8]* %0, i64 0
```

But when i use `setOperand()` on `%call` to replace the argument with `%1`, i get the aforementioned error. I guess `[12 x i8]*` is different from `i8*` but i can't find a way to cast it that works.

I've tried casting with `CreatePointerCast()` which created this:

```
%2 = addrspacecast [12 x i8]* %1 to i8 addrspace(8)*
```

But got the same error (the type for `%2` is `i8 addrspace(8)*` which is different from `i8*` i guess).

Also tries explicitly specifying the `i8*` type when creating the GEP:

```
Builder->CreateInBoundsGEP(llvm::Type::getInt8PtrTy(Ctx, 8), ...)
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using the `GEP` instruction wrongly.

Remember the first index steps over the pointer of type `[12 x i8]*`,which is what you supplied, and the second index specifies helps compute the starting address of the first character of your string, which is probably what you missed.